# ROOT.war file on Openshift

Tags: java, openshift, deploying

I've deployed Test.war file on Openshift and my application test-sliwa.rhcloud.com/Test run OK. When I deploy ROOT.file application test-sliwa.rhcloud.com doesn't run in right way - first page is ok, but when I try to link to other pages I have 404 error.

Comment: 404 is the file not found error — check to be sure your link addresses are correct. Post your code here so people can see what you've tried, and help you correct it.

Comment: App cannot run right when as ROOT.war deployed. In other case is ok. But I'd like to use ROOT.war

Comment: Here is index.jsp code . It works ok with servlet when as Test.war deployed. When as ROOT.war deployed I cannot link to adresses.

Comment: Here is index.jsp code . It works ok with servlet when as Test.war deployed. When as ROOT.war deployed I can't to link to adresses. <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="/Test/Controller?action=login">Login</a></p>
<p><a href="/Test/Controller?action=about">About</a></p>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in source code in links declared. It's better to declare domain-relative URL like:

```
<a href="<%= response.encodeUrl(request.getContextPath() + "/Controller?action=login") %>">
```

instead of:

```
<a href="Test/Controller?action=login")">}
```

in index.jsp file.